# What does `some_function` construction mean in Elm?

Tags: elm

I was looking into the `elm-form` package docs and found [here](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/etaque/elm-form/1.0.0/Form-Validate#andThen) this piece of code:

```hs
field "myfield" (int `andThen` minInt 10)
```

What do these quotes mean? Is it yet another way to apply a function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was a way to use any function as an infix, as in `3 + 5`.

BUT: It's been removed in elm 0.18: [migration notes.](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-platform/blob/master/upgrade-docs/0.18.md#backticks-and-andthen)